# Source code navigation for routes in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, slim, code-navigation

In PhpStorm, the *File Structure* (F12 on Mac) and *Structure* (⌘7) actions let you see a list of *functions* declared in the current file, so as to quickly jump to any of them.

Is there anything similar to **quickly navigate through route definitions**?

Consider this code that uses Slim PHP:

```php
$app->get('/test/icons/', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('test/icons.tpl');
});

$app->get('/foo/', function () use ($app) {
    /* whatever is going on here */
});

$app->get('/bar/', function () use ($app) {
    /* ditto */
});
```

I have a file with many dozens such routes spanning over a thousand lines and a quick navigation pane would be welcome.

Comment: Yes, there would be a way, but only if you use "Single Action Controllers".

Comment: No, this isn't available in PhpStorm. It would be great if you could submit this to our tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue